# Will this 4069-based CMOS low frequency oscillator schematic work?

Tags: oscillator, schematics, inverter, cmos

I'm into building synthesizers from scratch. I've recently built a low frequency oscillator as part of an instrument which works well, based on a TL074 quad op amp. However, it uses a heck of a lot of components and is rather 'clunky' as it requires a great deal of switching to allow 4 different waveforms (rising saw, falling saw, triangle and square).

I've been trying to improve this circuit by cutting down the components required so it can fit on a smaller piece of stripboard.

I found this image on google, with no context or explanation. Caption says it's just 'an idea'.

[image: CMOS Oscillator]

I have several 4069 chips and would like to try it. Before I commit it to perfboard, can anyone tell me if this schematic will actually work? And if so, what will the P-P amplitude of the waveforms be?

Comment: Got a breadboard? Breadboarding is a lot less commitment than perfboard.

Comment: I've nothing technical to offer, just think it's brilliant that you're building your own synths :-) Presumably they're true analogue rather than digital/hybrid.

Comment: The sine wave is only due to slew rate limiting of CMOS at max f

Comment: I managed to get this working in the end on breadboard, with a couple of adjustments. However, I forgot to write down the schematic and when I went to recreate it last night had totally forgotten what I did to make it work!

I even added a potentiometer so I could blend between the triangle square wave, added an LED via 1k resistor to pin 4 to show rate, and omitted the sine output altogether.

Now the LED just stays constantly lit and doesn't flash like it used to. I think maybe the resistor values 1M and 680k aren't quite right - I know in a hex schmitt they have to be roughly double.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy triangle square wave generator, your relaxation oscillator or this one to use. For a stable reference add 1 MHz Xtal and for really long time constants (2^14) add a CD4060 timer.

I did a quick and dirty design here using a log Pot with 4way cap selector with good tight wiring practice ;) in my [SIM.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+2+1e-9+222.68277840103303+1+10+50%0Aw+264+336+256+312+0%0Ar+352+368+352+304+0+1000%0Aw+432+304+432+368+2%0Aw+512+488+544+488+0%0Ac+248+408+208+408+2+0.000001+0.0009999999999919808%0Ag+208+408+208+424+0%0A211+432+368+512+368+0+1+8000+1%0Ac+208+368+248+368+0+1e-8+0.001%0A174+432+304+360+328+0+1000000+0.9950000000000001+Resistance+f%0Aw+432+304+432+328+0%0Aw+392+328+432+328+0%0A183+352+368+432+368+0+5+1.66+3.33%0A183+472+416+512+416+0+0.5+1.66+3.33%0A183+472+440+512+440+0+0.5+1.66+3.33%0A183+472+464+512+464+0+0.5+1.66+3.33%0A183+472+488+512+488+0+0.5+1.66+3.33%0A183+432+368+432+488+0+0.5+1.66+3.33%0Aw+472+416+472+440+0%0Aw+472+440+472+464+0%0Aw+472+464+472+488+0%0Aw+512+416+512+440+0%0Aw+512+440+512+464+0%0Aw+512+464+512+488+0%0Aw+472+488+432+488+0%0Ax+284+283+482+286+4+10+74HC14%5Cs5V%5Cs~50%5Csohms%5Cs%5Cs74ALC14%5Cs~25%5CsOhms%0Ax+511+452+587+455+4+10+buffered%5Csoutput%0Aw+584+368+584+304+0%0AS+312+368+264+368+0+2+false+0+4%0Aw+352+368+312+368+2%0Aw+264+384+248+408+0%0Ac+248+328+208+328+0+1e-10+1.7061883348371139%0Aw+248+368+264+368+0%0Aw+208+368+208+408+0%0Aw+264+352+248+328+0%0Aw+208+328+208+368+0%0Ar+352+368+352+384+0+1%0Ac+352+384+352+408+0+1e-12+1.7061911543748824%0Ag+352+408+352+416+0%0Ax+160+296+223+299+4+10+700k~44MHz%0Ar+352+368+304+416+0+1000%0Ax+141+369+191+372+4+10+70~12%5CskHz%0Ax+146+411+190+414+4+10+.7~120Hz%0Ax+142+331+197+334+4+10+7k~1.2%5CsMHz%0Ao+6+64+0+4362+5+0.1+0+1%0Ao+28+64+0+4354+5+0.00009765625+1+2+28+3%0A)
[image]

### Extra bits for misc. reasons.

- Good Cap Decoupling is mandatory, Ground plane is desirable.
- Then use twisted pair AWG 30 magnet wire for signal paths. (Poor man's coax)
- Using a wideband low input current Op Amp to buffer the inverter input triangle wave out is OPtional  (1/3 to 2/3 Vcc) and the unused Schmitt Inverters ganged for a buffer is a bonus.
- You can change the Series R and Pot from 1M and any caps to choose 1 decade, 2 or 3 which is a practical limit. So with 3 Caps I spanned almost > 7 decades.
- Choice of CMOS family is critical for max frequency and important for lower output impedance.  74ALCV being the lowest Z at 25 Ohms nom.

Comment: Thank you for this - I have to confess I don't understand a lot of it! It is a little advanced for me. Is that a 40106 chip? Also, where does that stray 1k resistor go to?

Comment: DNI , NC , not needed  yes 40106 is like 300 OHM 15V CD4xxx series <10MHz and ~ 1k RdsOn at 3V, if you need 15V ok, otherwise newer families for 5.5V max are lower impedance